# Rails/RSpec - How to write rspec tests for handlers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a handler which is responsible for creating a new record in db.It takes params from the POST requests and adds a new record to database.That helper is defined below:

```
module Vehicles
   module Handlers
      class AddVehicle
        def initialize(vehicle_params)
          @vehicle_info = vehicle_params
        end
    
        def call 
          create_vehicle
        end
    
        private
    
        def create_vehicle
          Vehicle.create!(@vehicle_info)
        end
      end
    end
end
```

I would like to test If that class methods work properly but without issuing the POST request.So I don't need to create data with factory_bot but simply puts arguments when calling the method.  Do you have an idea how to test this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handler is a class, so just need to do something like this...

```
h = Vehicle::Handlers::AddVehicle.new(vehicle_params)
```

to get an instance of the handler. Then you can test as you would any other class. For instance...

```
vehicle = h.call
refute_nil vehicle
```